# Insert RTF-Data without using clipboard or insertFile in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I've a question about inserting RTF Data into `Word.Range` objects. 
I implemented a program which fills Word bookmarks using values from the DB.

Currently I implemented two ways to fill RTF data into the Word bookmarks.

1. Save the RTF value to a temporary file and use the `InsertFile` method of the Range object.
2. Copy the RTF value to the clipboard. Select the range of the Word bookmark and use the `Paste` method.

Both methods have disadvantages which I can not handle:

I can't use the first way, because it writes a file on the harddisk and adds an newline character at the end of my RTF value/file. 
The second way erases the stored clipboard data.

**Is there a possibility to insert the data without using the clipboard or the InsertFile method?**

Comment: which programming language you are working with?

Comment: Word Open XML and the InsertXML method.